# Key error when looping through netCDF data dates

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I often work with satellite/model data, and a common task I need to perform is creating an array where every element is one of the months of the year. This generally works, but when I run the following code on an ECCO .nc file I get a key error that looks like a string of numbers (for example: KeyError: 727185600000000000)

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import ecco_v4_py as ecco
import os   



grid = ecco.load_ecco_grid_nc(grid_dir,'ECCO-GRID.nc')
ecco1992 = xr.merge((grid,xr.open_dataset('oceFWflx_1992.nc'))).load()

ts = []
    zero = 0
    for time in ecco1992.oceFWflx.time:
        ts.append(ecco1992.oceFWflx.sel(time=ecco1992.variables['time'][zero]))
        zero = zero+1
```

However, when I do this manually, it works fine, for example:

```
jan = ecco1992.oceFWflx.sel(time = '1992-01-16T12:00:00.000000000')
feb = ecco1992.oceFWflx.sel(time = '1992-02-15T12:00:00.000000000')
(rest of months)
ts.append(jan)
ts.append(feb)
ts.append(rest of months)
```

Yields the desired array, but isn't practical with large quantities of data.

What could the cause of this key error and how might I avoid it?

Comment: Try installing pandas version 1.05 or earlier. There was an update to how pandas handle indexes which has had knock on negative impacts on xarray, of the kind you are describing here

Comment: I appreciate it, this has mostly solved my problem. It still occurs on the merged dataset but I can at least do a work around by merging after for looping.